# Why is there an error while multiplying two integers in Swift?

Tags: swift, integer, multiplication

**Problem**: I was making some time slots and displaying them on my app. But I was getting one extra slot.

**While debugging** I came to know:
In my code at one step `528 * 2` is yielding `1057` as result not `1056`, due to which I am having extra slot.

As you can see in below image all variables here are integers. But why is there error in multiplication?

[image]

[image]

If you wonder. How we are calculating `totalHours`.

```swift
let totalHours = dateSelectorList.count * EpgLayoutSize.totalHoursInADay
```

```swift
public struct EpgLayoutSize {
    public static var totalHoursInADay: Int {
        return 24
    }
}
```

`EpgLayoutSize.totalHoursInADay` is fixed to `24`, and there were `22` elements in `dateSelectorList` array.
So calculation of `totalHours = 22 * 24 = 528` is correct here.

Comment: Multiplying an integer by 2 can never yield an odd value so there is something else going on here that is not part of the question or you have found a weird bug in Xcode.

Comment: I do not know if it is the cause, but the for loop start from `0` to `totalHeadersSlot`, so it will be executed `totalHeadersSlot + 1` times. Maybe this is the problem at execution, and debugger fails fetching the good values...

Comment: Two ways to `for` loop executed `totalHeadersSlot`times are `for hoursOffset in 0 ..< totalHeadersSlot` and `for hoursOffset in 1 ... totalHeadersSlot`.

Comment: Try printing it out after value get calculated and see the result

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but not all days have 24 hours in them in many time zones.